# Input image normalization for face recognition seems to hinder training

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to create neural network predicting face embeddings for face recognition. I'm basing architecture on [Facenet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf) Zeiler&Fergus model, which I've built in Keras. After first night of training on VGGFace2 dataset I've achieved accuracy of 80%. Training continued during the day up to 83%, but finally the network started overfitting and accuracy started falling.

I'm trying to improve accuracy now and I think that good place to start might be with image preprocessing. After reading a bit about normalization, centering and standardization I've implemented this function:

```
def normalize_batch(imgs):
  imgs = np.array(imgs, dtype=np.float32)
  per_channel_means = imgs.mean(axis=(0,1,2), dtype=np.float64)
  per_channel_stds = imgs.std(axis=(0,1,2), dtype=np.float64)
  imgs -= per_channel_means
  imgs /= per_channel_stds
  per_channel_max = np.absolute(imgs).max(axis=(0,1,2))
  imgs /= per_channel_max
  return imgs
```

I've been training network again with that augmentation applied in batch generator (`batch_size=39`), but so far loss function doesn't seem to go down like it was without it. Is there an error in the way I'm processing the data? Or maybe I should process it differently for this task?

Update: After night of training (35 epochs) loss function value didn't fall at all. I've started training again whilst removing following lines:

```
  per_channel_max = np.absolute(imgs).max(axis=(0,1,2))
  imgs /= per_channel_max
```

I wanted to bring values from current range of about <-3,3> to range <-1,1> , but I suspect there might be logic fault in the way I went about it with those two lines. I'm unsure If that's the issue, but loss has decreased with each of the 4 epochs I've trained so far.